# Convert integer to week interval

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

How one can convert integer to week interval?

```
CREATE TABLE integers( i integer);

INSERT INTO integers VALUES ('10');
```

Output would be table with one column indicating 10 weeks interval.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4b404/5/0

Comment: This is exactly the way to do it. What is your problem with it?

Comment: Well, I do not like the string constant. And also '1' in it. Also please upvote if answer is correct or help me to formulate it better so it is worth upvoting.

Comment: Why are you supplying a string constant for a column defined as an integer? Why not use a column of type `interval` directly?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name your question is well placed. Key/Value design was chosen for configuration parameters. Single row table would not have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One take would be to create constant interval of 1 week and multiply it by integer.
I would prefer function to do it directly, but I am not aware of it.

```
SELECT interval '1 week' * i AS weeks_interval FROM integers;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`make_interval(weeks => i)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-datetime.html). E.g.:

```sql
SELECT make_interval(weeks => i) AS weeks_interval FROM integers;
```

or

```sql
SELECT make_interval(0, 0, i) AS weeks_interval FROM integers;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is well accepted.

If you don't want to keep the "1" in the string you could write this instead

```
SELECT (i || 'week')::interval FROM intervals
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=53637d83e63855745ce80f91fde78b7f)